# Copy modified date from filename.zip and overwrite existing date in .ini file

Tags: file, powershell, ini, file-writing

I have a file with a modified date of *September 4th 2018*.

I want to copy that modified date of the file and paste it into an `.ini` file.

Before paste:

```
lastdbupdate=20180822 //YYYYMMDD
```

After paste:

```
lastdbupdate=20180904
```

So essentially, it's reading/copying the modified date from the file on my thumbdrive `E:\my folder\dbupdates\mynewdb.zip` and then opening an `.ini` file, finding the string, and replacing it with a MODIFIED date structure (changing from default date structure to `YYYYMMDD` in `C:\programs\program name\data\info.ini`.

Ive found several entries on getting the date, and for copying/pasting text, but I haven't been able to get these to work together!

Any chance anyone has an idea or an article suggestion that addresses both of these?

Comment: Hi David! Can you share the code you've tried so far, please?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I apologise for the corrections. I tried to offer the right amount of info but guess I screwed that up.

Comment: Thank you, Gvee. I will be home from work in a while and will try to provide the information requested. Try meaning... In a manner consistent with clijsters reply.

Answer (score 0):

- First check the existence of both files
- then get the properties of the zip and format the `.LastWriteTime` to `yyyyMMdd`
- use a RegEx with a zero length [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion to replace the `lastdbupdate`

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\09\06\SO_52196744.ps1

$dbzip   = 'E:\my folder\dbupdates\mynewdb.zip'
$inifile = 'C:\programs\program name\data\info.ini'

If ((Test-Path $dbzip) -and (Test-Path $iniFile)){
    $lastdbupdate=(Get-Item $dbzip).LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd')
    (Get-Content $iniFile) -replace "(?<=^lastdbupdate=)\d{8}.*$",$lastdbupdate |
     Set-Content $iniFile
}
```

Comment: I am very thankful for this! It looks wildly different than what I have piecemealed together, but that means nothing other than I may have really been on the wrong track!  When I get home, I will run this and post results! Thank you for taking the time!!